# git line log (git -L) suppress diff

Tags: git, git-log

`git log --format=%H -L12,45:file.txt -s` will always output the diff for each commit. It seems to ignore the `-s` flag when doing line-based logging. How can I fix this?

git version 2.1.4 as well as 1.9.4.msysgit.1 . Both on Windows.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I posted a bug report to the mailing list here: https://public-inbox.org/git/CAEkQehdFu5zM4AY3ihN0pn1aCNEomY0WV07pryfAB45JN-tDDA@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Answer (score 0):

This is *really* not what I would like, but if nothing else works, I can pipe git log output to grep. For example:

```
git log -s -L680,738:file.txt --format=%H | grep '^[^@+-][^i]'
```

This solution will technically not work if the desired formatted output is filtered out by the regex, but I don't see that happening in practice with this regex.